# Update a variable in Python correctly

Tags: python, variables

I am calling the below function from another module and am attempting to update the variable `cur` as I move through the code.  It's fairly simple.  If the attribute move equals north than the variable should change from `1` to `2`.  However, this update is not happening and I am stuck.  I feel it should be very simple.  How would I update this variable?

```
import objects
def movement(move):
    cur = 1
    if cur == 1:
        if move == "north":
            cur = cur + 1
            return "You stand in front of the white house."

        if move == "south":
            return "To the south there is tall grass as far as the eye can see.  But it is getting dark.  You decide to stay put."

        if move == "east":
            return "Darkness creeps up across the tall grassy feilds in the east.  You decide to stay put."

        if move == "west":
            return "You stand in a dark forest to the west."

    if cur == 2:
        if move == "south":         
            cur = cur - 1
            return "You stand facing a white house in the north.  Grassy feilds surround you and the sun is setting behind a forest in the west. " + objects.Mailbox.obj()
```

Comment: how do you know the variable "cur" wasn't updated? it's a local variable, if you call the function from elsewhere it shouldn't be visible as it is destroyed at the end of your function run

Comment: Every time you call the function, `cur` is set to 1 again.

Comment: By *update is not happening* do you expect the code to enter the second if-condition (i.e. `if cur == 2:`)? If not, please elaborate and clarify the point you're not happy with.

Answer (score 0):

if you want your `cur` to be updated, you'll have to make movement a class, and cur a member like so:

```py
import objects

class MovementClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cur = 1
    def movement(self, move):
        if self.cur == "north":
            self.cur += 1
            return "You stand in front of the white house."

        if move == "south":
            return "To the south there is tall grass as far as the eye can see.  But it is getting dark.  You decide to stay put."

        if move == "east":
            return "Darkness creeps up across the tall grassy feilds in the east.  You decide to stay put."

        if move == "west":
            return "You stand in a dark forest to the west."

        if self.cur == 2:
            if move == "south":         
                self.cur -= 1
                return "You stand facing a white house in the north.  Grassy feilds surround you and the sun is setting behind a forest in the west. " + objects.Mailbox.obj()
```

This way your `cur` will be updated, and you will be able to access it